# Hide a custom column field via SuiteScript based on an option from a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I need to show a custom transaction column field in Netsuite. Netsuite Support Team is useless as well as Netsuite Support website. Can anybody help me with this? I need the field display type to be set to NORMAL when certain options from a dropdown menu are chosen, otherwise, it needs to be hidden.

Comment: Hope this will help https://support.farapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/236122347-Adding-Custom-Transaction-Column-Fields-in-NetSuite

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this wholly client side.
Once a list is displayed on a page the columns are fixed.

Your options include:

- Use a suitelet and display your header fields as a first page and then your colum fields on the next page after the determining drop-downs have been selected
- Make the fields you'd like to hide display only when the drop-downs are selected so at least they are not as much of a bother
- Make the column area an inline html table that you control completely.

That last isn't has horrible as it may sound since you can couple that with a hidden sublist of the real items and edit via pop-up suitelet driven dialogs. i.e. the inline table is read-only except for an Edit button. The Edit button triggers a dialog that is sourced from a Suitelet. You do that in an iframe and the post returns a function that populates the selected values. You can also dynamically update the table and skip the post or only add an action button to the suitelet dialog that updates the parent values.